# Access Invoicing Price problems

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am building an Access database, but am having an issue with the relationships. I have 2 unique and indexed field columns in  one table, and one indexed (but not unique) one.

I want to either :

A) Set the second table to allow me to simply fill in one field with the primary key of the first table, and have it fill in the rest of the information automatically based on that.

or

B) Be able to select the non-unique entry (they are prices- hence my inability to simply make them unique) from a drop down on the second table.

Comment: I may actually need to close the question. I've since decided that autofill is more along the lines of what I want. But- at the time, my issue was that I was attempting to use data integrity, as I wanted to make use of a dropdown for the prices in a table (I want to use set prices and disallow users to have the freedom to simply type in any arbitrary value).

Comment: By and large- it's just been a hectic game of using the lookup tool wizard a lot of different times under several options + trial and error. https://www.dropbox.com/s/rgeyh9ifjn17q0y/New%20folder.zip?dl=0